# Extract File with no extension via 7-zip through Powershell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I have the below files (Datamashup files of PowerBI) which do not have any extensions.
[image]

We manually extract the file via 7-zip tool as below:

[image]

How can one extract it via powershell ?

Note: I tried leveraging Expand-7Zip module but it is not working as the file extension is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zett42 fyi 7zip removed 7za, just 7z is the cmdline tool now.

@Nandan, just replace the folder path below with your folder path

```
get-childitem c:\temp\ -File -Filter *. | %{& 7z e $_.FullName}
```

Or if you place the script in the same folder:

```
get-childitem $PSScriptRoot -File -Filter *. | %{& 7z e $_.FullName}
```

Note: You'll need to add 7zip to your Path variable as well, alternatively just reference the full path to the 7z exe e.g. "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

edit2: If you want to stick with windows only do the below.

```
get-childitem $PSScriptRoot -File -Filter *. | %{Expand-Archive $_.FullName}
```

Comment: If you have 7-zip in PATH, you can omit `&` and just write `7z e $_.FullName`. Only for full path you need `&`.

Comment: Thank you @mike .It worked but a query, is there any other way we can extract the file rather than setting up 7 zip tool in the system but importing some powershell modules ? Because not every system have security approval to install that tool

Comment: @Nandan I've edited the answer to remove 7zip